Loading a Vue3 page in a WebView in an Android project. Android project launches with a blank rendering screen
When I try to display a frontend interface developed with Vue 3 in an Android app using WebView, the Android project launches with a blank rendering screen. The logcat shows the following log information,
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Access to script at 'file:///android_asset/vue_dist/assets/index-CMX_iLam.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.", source: file:///android_asset/vue_dist/index.html (1)

The Vue 3 project I built opens in the local browser with the same issue in the console. My solution was to start a local HTTP server, which successfully renders Vue components in the browser. Now, I need to load the Vue 3 built pages using WebView in an Android project in Android Studio.
And the MainActivity code in Android is as follows. How can this issue be resolved?
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            WebViewScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WebViewScreen() {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.allowFileAccess = true
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                loadUrl("file:///android_asset/vue_dist/index.html")
            }
        }
    )
}


I tried adding the following permissions in MainActivity, but still could not load the Vue components.
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
settings.allowFileAccess = true
settings.domStorageEnabled = true


You may need to add a header in your page to allow CORS. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work
